# Error reading characters of string - for a string value in an array

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make a program that reads lines from a text files about information for a dvd. After feeding information to the custom dvd class, I am going to be printing it. Currently, when using debugger, it shows the below errors for each of the parameters of the custom class. Please help.

> Error reading characters of string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class dvd
{
    string movieName, movieProdComp, movieLeadActor, movieLanguage, renterName;
    string releaseYear, rentDate, returnDate;
public:
    dvd() {};
    dvd(string line) {};
    dvd(string mn, string mpc, string mla, string ml, string rn, string ry, string rd, string retd);
    void print();
};

dvd::dvd(string mn, string mpc, string mla, string ml, string rn, string ry, string rd, string retd) {
    movieName = mn;
    movieProdComp = mpc;
    movieLeadActor = mla;
    movieLanguage = ml;
    renterName = rn;
    releaseYear = ry;
    rentDate = rd;
    returnDate = retd;
}

void dvd::print() {
    cout << "Movie:" << movieName << endl;
    cout << "Production:" << movieProdComp << endl;
    cout << "Starring:" << movieLeadActor << endl;
    cout << "Language:" << movieLanguage << endl;
    cout << "Rented By:" << renterName << endl;
    cout << "Released:" << releaseYear << endl;
    cout << "Rent Date:" << rentDate << endl;
    cout << "Return Date:" << returnDate << endl;
}

int main() {
    string filepath = "C:\\Users\\SuperUser\\Google Drive\\COMP306\\TMA2\\test.txt";
    string line;
    ifstream file(filepath);
    string arrayDvd[10][8];
    if (file.is_open())
    {

        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {   
            arrayDvd[n][c] = line;
            i++;
            c++;
            if (i > 7)
            {
                n++;
                c=i = 0;
            }           
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++) 
    {
        //this is where the error shows.
        dvd dvdS[] = { arrayDvd[n][0], arrayDvd[n][1], arrayDvd[n][2], arrayDvd[n][3], arrayDvd[n][4], arrayDvd[n][5], arrayDvd[n][6], arrayDvd[n][7] };
    }
}
```

Data: The below strings are repeated 10 times. [Full data](https://pastebin.com/YLNtZwpz)

Zombie1
BBC
James
English
Alw
2012
20170601
20170630

Comment: Do yourself a favor and start using `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Is that not what I have used - string arrayDvd? Sorry, new to C++

Comment: No `string arrayDvd[10][8];` has nothing to do with `std::vector`.

Comment: I was referring to the std::array part of your suggestion. Or are you talking about just sticking with single dimensional arrays?

Comment: You need to learn about `std::vector`, `std::array` and how to use them properly.

Comment: Also as we don't know what is the format of that text file, it is better to provide that too. Generally speaking, it is recommended to use an standard format like CSV or something similar.

Comment: @Sinapse Added. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
dvd dvdS[] = { arrayDvd[n][0], arrayDvd[n][1], arrayDvd[n][2], arrayDvd[n][3], arrayDvd[n][4], arrayDvd[n][5], arrayDvd[n][6], arrayDvd[n][7] };
```

to

```
dvd dvdS{ arrayDvd[n][0], arrayDvd[n][1], arrayDvd[n][2], arrayDvd[n][3], arrayDvd[n][4], arrayDvd[n][5], arrayDvd[n][6], arrayDvd[n][7] };
```

The former creates a c-style array of 8 instances using the one parameter constructor (that does nothing), and the latter creates one instance using the 8-parameter constructor.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. The worst part is that I have done this one time before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this

```
std::vector<dvd> dvds;
for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++) 
{
    dvds.push_back(dvd(arrayDvd[n][n*7+0], arrayDvd[n][n*7+1], arrayDvd[n][n*7+2], arrayDvd[n][n*7+3], arrayDvd[n][n*7+4], arrayDvd[n][n*7+5], arrayDvd[n][n*7+6], arrayDvd[n][n*7+7]));
}
```

This will create an array (wrapped by std::vector) and pushed every dvd object in it. Also you don't need the variable `i` remove it and instead of checking `i > 7` check if `c > 7`